# How to group by List<object> ViewModel in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, group-by

I want to group by `vitaminlist`, but it's not working.

My Model

```cs
public class SearchModel
{
    public List<tbbesin> besinlist { get; set; }
    public List<tbvitamin> vitaminliste { get; set; }
    public List<tbmineral> mineralliste { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```cs
public ActionResult ara(BesinViewModel model)
{
    var listegetir = model.besinler.Split(',');

    List<tbbesin> besinliste = new List<tbbesin>();
    List<tbmineral> minerallist = new List<tbmineral>();
    List<tbvitamin> vitaminlist = new List<tbvitamin>();    
    SearchModel modelden = new SearchModel();

    foreach (var item in listegetir)
    {
        var ID = int.Parse(item);
        var besin = db.tbbesin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.besinid == ID);
        var mineral = db.tbmineral.FirstOrDefault(x => x.besinid == ID);
        var vitamin = db.tbvitamin.FirstOrDefault(x => x.besinid == ID);

        vitaminlist.Add(vitamin);
        minerallist.Add(mineral);
        besinliste.Add(besin);
    }

    modelden.besinlist = besinliste.ToList();
    modelden.mineralliste = minerallist.ToList();
    modelden.vitaminliste = vitaminlist.ToList();

    return View(modelden);
}
```

My View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.SearchModel
@foreach (var item22 in Model.vitaminliste.
    GroupBy(x => x.vitamindetayid).
    Select(x=>x.First()).
    ToList())
{
    @item22.tbvitamindetay.vitaminad
}
```

**I need to group by in view vitaminlist but its not working.
Why ?** **Can you help me what is a problem there**

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*, that's gives any error?

Comment: Are you getting duplicates or nothing? It look like you are grouping on a class and not an individual item.  You have item22.tbvitamindetay.vitaminad which means tbvitamindetay is a class and to group on class you would need to inherit IEquality<T>.

Comment: there is not error , its working but 5 records are required but 4 records are coming

Comment: can you put some data, the 5 records

Comment: Did you check whether `Model.vitaminliste` contains the expected items, with the expected `vitamindetayid` values, in the first place?

Comment: I need this data: A , B , C , D but its came A,B,D